# WPF Set border left and width

Tags: wpf

I need to set the left and width of a border.  I'm trying to use margin

```
b.Margin = new Thickness(pb.X, b.Margin.Top, b.Margin.Right, b.Margin.Bottom);
```

but if I set the Width property the border is placed in an incorrect strange position... (the half screen + half of the left that i want).

how can i do the trick?

thanks

Comment: Where is this logic?  If it is inside your MeasureOverride(Size constraint) method, then @Snowbear's answer will help. You would also need to do something similar inside ArrangeOverride().  Otherwise, can you provide some more detail?

Comment: You are trying to set the "left and width" or "length and width"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var totalAvailableWidth = ...; // you will have to get it somewhere
var marginRight = totalAvailableWidth - pb.X - width;
b.Margin = new Thickness(pb.X, b.Margin.Top, marginRight, b.Margin.Bottom);
```

Comment: thanks, i need rest...      totalAvailableWidth = ((FrameworkElement)b.Parent).ActualWidth;